# Using purrr and select to create dichotomous variables

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm trying to create columns of dichotomous variables based on presence (or absence) of selected continuous variables.

Example:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(z = c(0, 0), a_1 = c(.1, NA), a_2 = c(NA, .1))

out <- tibble(z = c(0, 0),
              a_1 = c(.1, NA), 
              a_2 = c(NA, .1), 
              a_1_d = c(1, 0), 
              a_2_d = c(0, 1))
```

I can do this on an ad hoc basis using `mutate`:

```
out <- df %>% 
  mutate(a_1_d = if_else(is.na(a_1), 0, 1)) %>% 
  mutate(a_2_d = if_else(is.na(a_2), 0, 1))
```

But my real use case involves a lot of variables, so I'd like to use `purrr` and `dplyr::select`. I've tried a bunch of approaches, such as:

```
out <- df %>% 
  select(starts_with("a_")) %>% 
  map(.x, .f = mutate({{.x}}_d = 
                        if_else(is.na(.x), 0, 1)))
```

But I think I'm missing something fundamental about some combination of name assignment within `map` and passing variables to `map`. What is the most efficient way to get from `df` to `out` using a `purrr` function and `dplyr::select`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you feel about `mutate()` with `across()`? That seems like a good tool for this sort of problem.

You can choose which columns to work "across" with tidy select functions just like in `select()`. We then give the function we want to use on each column. You'll see I used `as.numeric()` on the logical output of "not NA" (`!is.na`) to 0/1 but you could absolutely use `if_else()` here, as well. I use the **purrr**-style lambda in the function (i.e., ~).

To add a suffix to new columns to be added to the dataset I use a named list for `.fns`.

```
mutate(df, across(.cols = starts_with("a"),
                  .fns = list(d = ~as.numeric(!is.na(.x)))))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>       z   a_1   a_2 a_1_d a_2_d
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     0   0.1  NA       1     0
#> 2     0  NA     0.1     0     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>